# Class Validator is not working with nestjs

Tags: nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

I have some projects with nestjs, I've always used the class validator, but recently it doesn't seem to be working. It simply doesn't call the DTO to validate.

controller

```
@Post()
  async create(@Body() body: UserDTO) {
    return body;
  }
```

My DTO

```
import { IsNotEmpty, IsString } from 'class-validator';

export class UserDTO {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  name: string;
}
```

main

```
app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
      forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
      transform: true,
    }),
  );
```

versions class validator and class transformer

```
"class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
"class-validator": "^0.13.2",
```

Comment: Can you show a sample request as well so we can verify what should be validating here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved, the solution was to instantiate the validation pipe inside the input module

```
@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot(), UserModule, AuthModule],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_PIPE,
      useValue: new ValidationPipe({
        whitelist: true,
        forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
        transform: true,
      }),
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: This should be not necessary if you are declaring it as a GlobalPipe

Comment: Yes, but the way it is in the documentation didn't work, I've used it in other projects and it works correctly, I even created a new project, just adding the class-validator, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share the request you were making?. I have the exact code and works as expected